# In C# XML Documentation, only the summary tag is working

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to add XML documentation for my homework on VS code, but only text in the summary block shows up when hovering over the function/variable.

It also happened in the normal Visual Studio and on multiple computers, so I figure it's just something I don't understand, but I tried googling it and came up with nothing. [I've also tried just straight up copy-pasting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44YsC.jpg) from a [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc), but [it still did not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9UVN.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Visual Studio intellisense to show the remarks portion of XML comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645744/how-to-make-visual-studio-intellisense-to-show-the-remarks-portion-of-xml-commen)

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035404/how-to-see-full-document-generated-by-xml-comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the intellisense only shows you the summary.  It will never show you remarks or exceptions, but if you use it on a method, you will see the intellisense for each parameter as you enter them.

Comment: Thanks! I've worked a lot with Java this past year so I guess I just instinctively assumed it worked like Javadoc.